# Get a bundles object/instance

Tags: symfony

How would I go about obtaining the instance of a specific bundle?

In trying to adhere to this best practice:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#constants-vs-configuration-options

I would like to stick some configuration details in a global bundle as they are likely to rarely change but are not specific to any given entity or bundle. Multiple bundles from multiple entities can use this to pre-populate a "Unit of Measure" drop down.

So I have done something like:

```
class ZincBundle extends Bundle {

    private $units = [
        'PCS'    => 'PCS',
        'LOT'    => 'LOT',
        'LBS'    => 'LBS',
        'SET'    => 'SET',
        'EACH' => 'EACH'
    ];

    public function getUnitsOfMeasure ()
    {
        return $this->units;
    }

}
```

Now I am trying to access this to populate some forms - this is what I have:

```
$container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
//$bundle = $this->container->get('ZincBundle');
```

What am I missing???

Comment: Make units a class constant then use ZincBundle::units.  However, I think you may be reading too much into the recommended practices.

Comment: That was actually supposed to be part of the question haha. Whether or not this was a worse practice then just keeping in the config files.

Comment: If you only using it for forms the make a UnitsFormType and then just use it in your other forms.  The docs show you how.  Otherwise, yes, stick it in a config file and inject where needed.

Comment: FormType is a neat idea...thx